# Modifiers resetting amount / segments value

Tags: modifiers, bevel, drivers

There is a problem with bevel modifier values I encounter when reopening a .blend file after saved. After I erased the objects' value links to a driver (a way of borrowing another object chosen value and translated) the new values are resetting to some default values an that seem fine to me but this situation repeats every time I reopen the saved .blend file, even if I saved it afterwards changes and in consequence my custom value resets to default.

What can I do to make them keep de custom values I assign to them ?

Comment: Hello ! Are you using keyframes for these values ? (Are they animated ?)

Comment: I checked and it seems there are not any shapekeys and keyframes involved

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Make sure to delete all drivers even of you change the type (of width in case of bevel modifiers). The quick way to do it is to open driver editor and select object you want to clean out of drivers.